# AWS: Share "NAT Gateway" among VPCs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I have one VPC where i configured **NAT Gateway**. Another VPC(s) do not have any "public subnet" nor IGW. I would like to share single NAT Gateway among many VPCs.
I tried to configure Routing table but it does not allow to specify NAT Gateway from different VPC.
As posible solution, I installed http/s proxy in VPC with IGW and configured proxy settings on every instance in different VPC. It worked, but I would like use **NAT Gateway** due to easier management.
Is it possible to make this kind of configuration at AWS?
There are few VPCs and I do not want to add NAT Gateway to each VPC.

Zdenko

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[AWS Transit Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/transit-gateway/) now provides an option to do what you wish, although you will want to consider the costs involved -- there are hourly and data charges. There is a reference architecture published in which multiple VPCs share a NAT gateway without allowing traffic between the VPCs:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/creating-a-single-internet-exit-point-from-multiple-vpcs-using-aws-transit-gateway/

Comment: Thanks.
I am aware of this new feature. As you mentioned, cost is factor taken into consideration.

Comment: @zdenko.s could you mark this the official answer, as things have changed since 2016?

Answer (score 8):

You can't share a NAT Gateway among multiple VPCs.

To access a resource in another VPC without crossing over the Internet and back requires VPC peering or another type of VPC-to-VPC VPN, and these arrangements do not allow transit traffic, for very good reasons.  Hence:

> You cannot route traffic to a NAT gateway through a VPC peering connection, a VPN connection, or AWS Direct Connect. A NAT gateway cannot be used by resources on the other side of these connections.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-nat-gateway.html#nat-gateway-other-services

The instances in the originating VPC are, by definition, "on the other side of" one of the listed interconnection arrangements.

Comment: Thanks,
In this case, I have to create NAT instance.

Comment: A very good answer at the time, it is now out of date. See the AWS Transit Gateway answer below.

Answer (score 3):

You basically have 3 options

- connect to a shared VPC (typically in a shared "network" account) that holds the NAT via VPC peering. No additional costs for the VPC peering, but cumbersome to setup if you have a lot of accounts
- same, but using Transit Gateway. A Peering Attachment is almost the same cost as a single NAT, so this will only save costs if you use multiple NAT gateways to have a high bandwidth
- Setup a shared VPC (e.g. in an infrastructure account that holds the NAT. Then share private subnets via AWS resource manager (RAM) to the VPCs that need outgoing access. This has the additional benefit you have a single place where you allocate VPC IP ranges and not every account needs to bother with setting up the full VPC. More details in [AWS VPC sharing best practices](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/vpc-sharing-key-considerations-and-best-practices/). This setup avoids both the Transit Gateway costs and the burden of setting up VPC peering. But needs more careful planning to keep things isolated (and likely not everything in the same VPC)